# How to allow only command line operations (CRUD) of database table?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have a admins table. I want to restrict CRUD (create, update, delete) of admin rows in database to be possible in 'bin\cake console' and disable REST-functions.

How should I modify my scaffolded Admins (-Controller, -Model) ?

Comment: Just don't implement create, update and delete methods in your controllers?

Comment: How do I make these operations with console commands? Create Model Entity object and manipulate that directly?

Comment: Yeah, that's how you'd have to do it anyway, it's not good form to be trying to call into controllers from the command line.